# How to execute the results of a pipe in csh?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I need to execute the results of a pipe, but without using a temp file (the pid needs to stay the same...dang screwy regression system).

So, if I have a test file that contains:

```
echo Do this
```

I ideally want to run something like:

```
cat test_file | eval
```

That would return this:

```
Do this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
eval `cat test_file`
```

But look out for [code injection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Comment: That was it.  I knew there was something simple like that.  Thanks!!